# Counting the Number of Dates When Larger Than Another Date - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have no idea where to start with this, but what I am trying to do is create a new value based on the number of times another value is represented in another column.

For example

```
# Existing Data
key newcol
a   ?
a   ?
a   ?
b   ?
b   ?
c   ?
c   ?
c   ?
```

Would like the output to look like

```
key newcol
a   3
a   3
a   3
b   2
b   2
c   3
c   3
c   3
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should read some introductory material and show what you tried. Everything you need to know for this is in the [Introduction to `dplyr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html). If you try a couple things and they don't work, we can help you work through the problems.

Comment: Question title has nothing to do what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `doBy` package like so:

```
require(doBy)

#original data frame
df <- data.frame(key = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'))

#add counter 
df$count <- 1

#use summaryBy to count number of instances of key
counts <- summaryBy(count ~ key, data = df, FUN = sum, var.names = 'newcol', keep.names = TRUE)

#merge counts into original data frame
df <- merge(df, counts, by = 'key', all.x = TRUE)
```

`df` then looks like:

```
> df
  key count newcol
1   a     1      3
2   a     1      3
3   a     1      3
4   b     1      2
5   b     1      2
6   c     1      3
7   c     1      3
8   c     1      3
```

Answer (score -1):

If `key` is a vector like this `key <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), c(3,2,3))`, then you can get what you want by using `table` to count occurences of `key` elements

```
> N <- table(key)
> data.frame(key, newcol=rep(N,N))
  key newcol
1   a      3
2   a      3
3   a      3
4   b      2
5   b      2
6   c      3
7   c      3
8   c      3
```

On the other hand, if `key` is a data.frame, then...

```
key.df <- data.frame(key = rep(letters[1:3], c(3, 2, 3)))
N <- table(key.df$key)
data.frame(key=key.df, newcol=rep(N, N))
```

Comment: For the downvoter, please provide feedback. Why did I get a downvote?